# Trouble with imageStore() (OpenGL 4.3)

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, compute-shader

I'm trying to output some data from compute shader to a texture, but imageStore() seems to do nothing. Here's the shader:

```
#version 430

layout(RGBA32F) uniform image2D image;

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;
void main() {
    imageStore(image, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

and the application code is here:

```
GLuint tex;

glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);

glBindImageTexture(0, tex, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
glUseProgram(program->GetName());
glUniform1i(program->GetUniformLocation("image"), 0);

glDispatchCompute(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1);
```

then a full screen quad is rendered with that texture but currently it only shows some random old data from video memory. Any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT:

This is how I display the texture:

```
// This comes right after the previous block of code
glUseProgram(drawProgram->GetName());

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glUniform1i(drawProgram->GetUniformLocation("sampler"), 0);

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glfwSwapBuffers();
```

and the drawProgram consists of:

```
#version 430
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location : require

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
out vec2 uvCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    uvCoord = position;
}
```

and:

```
#version 430

in vec2 uvCoord;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = (uvCoord + vec2(1.0f)) / 2.0f;
    uv.y = 1.0f - uv.y;

    color = texture(sampler, uv);
    //color = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

The last commented line in fragment shader produces this output: [Render output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ZPh.jpg)

The vertex array object (vao) has one buffer with 6 2D vertices:

-1.0, -1.0

1.0, -1.0

1.0, 1.0

1.0, 1.0

-1.0, 1.0

-1.0, -1.0

Comment: "*Any idea what could be wrong?*" I have a lot of ideas of what could be wrong, but first we need to see how you're trying to display the image.

Comment: @NicolBolas I added more information about displaying the texture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is how I display the texture:

That's not good enough. I don't see a [call to `glMemoryBarrier`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMemoryBarrier), so there's no guarantee that your code actually works.

Remember: writes to images via [Image Load/Store](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) are not memory coherent. They [require explicit user synchronization before they become visible](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access). If you want to use an image you have stored to as a texture later, there *must* be an explicit `glMemoryBarrier` call after the rendering command that writes to it, but before the rendering command that samples from it as a texture.

> Why that is a problem, I don't know

Because desktop OpenGL is *not* OpenGL ES.

The last three parameters *only* describe the [arrangement of the pixel data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) you're giving OpenGL. They change *nothing* about how OpenGL stores the data. In ES, they do, but that's only because ES doesn't do format conversions.

In desktop OpenGL, it is perfectly legal to upload floating-point data to a normalized integer texture; OpenGL is expected to convert the data as best it can. ES doesn't do conversions, so it has to change the *internal format* (the third parameter) to match the data.

Desktop GL does not. If you want a specific [image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format), you ask for it. Desktop GL gives you what you ask for, and only what you ask for.

Always use sized internal formats.

Answer (score 4):

GL_RGBA is not a sized internal format and so you're not able to know which it is really. Most often, it is transformed to GL_RGBA8 by OpenGL.

In your case, the GL_FLOAT parameter you set only describes the pixel data you **could** upload in the texture.

Read the table 2 [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) to know what you can set as an internal texture format.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I found the solution. The problem lies here:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

this line doesn't specify the size of the internal format (GL_RGBA). When I supplied GL_RGBA32F it started working. Why that is a problem, I don't know (hopefully somebody will be able to explain).