# imageStore() doesn't work on AMD hardware (OpenGL 4.2)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I tried this code on Nvidia hardware without any problem but on AMD, the imageStore() function  doesn't seem to do anything (No GL error is thrown though, I checked)

**Shader:**

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store : require

layout(size4x32) uniform image2D A;
void main(void){
    vec4 output = vec4(0.111, 0.222 , 0.333, 0.444);
    imageStore(A, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy-vec2(0.5,0.5)), output);
}
```

**Calling Program:**

```
glUseProgram(program);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation (program , "A" ), id);

glBindImageTexture(id, texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

//Bind the fbo associated with the texture to run a shader per pixel
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);  //Forbid gl_FragColor to be modified

//Render a quad
draw();

//Then read the texture...
```

As suggested in an other thread by Nicol Bolas  ([Trouble with imageStore() (OpenGL 4.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285849/trouble-with-imagestore-opengl-4-3)) I tried to add some barriers to insure that the memory is written when I read back the texture but no change, the texture that imageStore is supposed to write to is not modified.

```
void main(void){
   vec4 output = vec4(0.111, 0.222 , 0.333, 0.444);
   memoryBarrier();
   imageStore(A, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), output);
   memoryBarrier();
}
```

In the main program:

```
...
draw();
glMemoryBarrierEXT(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
...
```

On the other hand, if I remove glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE) to simply output my value using gl_FragColor it works, as usual:

```
void main(void){
   gl_FragColor = vec4(0.111, 0.222 , 0.333, 0.444);
}
```

but I really need to do it with imageStore since I want to use scatter writes.
I also tried to use imageLoad and didn't have any problem. What is happening with this imageStore function?

Any ideas?

Comment: `#extension GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store : require` Please don't confuse the implementation this way. If you're using GLSL 4.20, it's a *core feature*. You don't activate it with a `#extension` directive.

Comment: "*Bind the fbo associated with the texture to run a shader per pixel*" What does that mean? Are you saying that the FBO you bound has the same texture you're trying to read from?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guess it would it be sufficient to declare #version 420 on the top of my shader to be able to use the image load/store functionality...

Comment: Yes, I am binding the fbo of the same texture I want to write to with imageStore (without writing on it using gl_FragColor) just to force the pipeline to run a shader by pixel. It worked without problem on Nvidia but it is not working on AMD >_<
I would prefer to use a compute shader instead of using this trick but my driver does not support OpenGL 4.3 yet.
Also, I tried to bind the fbo of an other texture (having the same size of the texture I want to write to) but it did not work better

Answer (score 0):

I probably had the same problem with AMD card as you. I then looked at the source code of OpenGL Sample Pack at : http://www.g-truc.net/project-0026.html#menu

In studying this source code related to imageStore, I found that adding two following lines for the texture made my code work for AMD  (the code in java)

gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);

If it does not work for you, just compare your code with OpenGL Sample Pack to find more.

Comment: I checked my code but I already used NEAREST for TEXTURE_MIN/MAG_FILTER so it must be something else in my case... However, I compiled the code of OpenGL Sample Pack from your link and it seems to work fine. Thanks for the advice, I will try to use this code and mix it with mine until I find the problem!

Comment: After a quick look, the problem may be due:  
**(1.)** To the use of GL_RGBA32F whereas a GL_RGBA8 format is used in the sample pack  
**(2.)** To the use of a FBO and glReadPixel in my code to retrieve the texture  
**(3.)** To the use in my code of (possibly) deprecated functions in OpenGL 4